# Filling in missing values with values that may exist elsewhere in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an aviation dataset that I am trying to clean. There are some missing values for the `NumEngines` feature, but there are some instances where a missing value can be derived from an entry elsewhere in the dataframe (this is not always the case). Below is a mini example of my dataset to illustrate both cases. Note that first Cessna entry can be used to fill in the second, but this is not the case for Piper.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Make"] = ["Cessna","Piper","Cessna","Boeing"]
df["Model"] = ["Citation","PA32RT","Citation","737-300"]
df["NumEngines"] = [2,None,None,2]
```

How can I make it so that the resulting DataFrame would be

```
     Make     Model  NumEngines
0  Cessna  Citation         2.0
1   Piper    PA32RT         NaN
2  Cessna  Citation         2.0
3  Boeing   737-300         2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet `transform('first')` could make it again here:

```
df.groupby(['Make', 'Model']).transform('first')
Out[179]: 
   NumEngines
0         2.0
1         NaN
2         2.0
3         2.0
```

Comment: What does the parameter "first" do?

Comment: Takes the first non na value of the subgroup